# Cucumber Full Support Extension in VS code isn't working for me

Tags: visual-studio-code, automation, protractor, cucumber

**Describe the bug:**
Curly lines are displayed in the feature file even when step definitions are available and properly mentioned in the settings.json file
Go to step definitions and Peek Step definitions options aren't displayed
Note: I'm literally unable to get help from anywhere apart from creating an bug.

**Expected behavior:**
User should be displayed Curly lines only for steps which doesn't have step definitions and user should be able to Go to step definitions from feature files

**Image of my Project structure & Issue:**
[image: Image of my Project structure & Issue]

**Image of my settings.json:**
[image]

**Project Structure Sample:**

```
-PROJECT NAME
  -featureFiles
    -features1.feature
    -features1.feature
  -stepDefinitions
    -stepDefintions_1.ts
    -stepDefintions_2.ts
    -stepDefintions_3.ts
  -pageObjects
  -logs
  -configFiles
  -commonUtlities
  -node_modules
  -reports
  -package.json
  -ts-config.json
```

**Settings.json file:**

```
{
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": ["stepDefinitions/*.ts"],
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "featureFiles/*feature",
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinValidation": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.smartSnippets": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.stepsInvariants": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons"
}
```

Please assist me in resolving my issue or identifying, where I have gone wrong :(

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Copy and paste the code into your question and click the "Code" icon to format it.

Comment: Thanks @Greg. I have done the formatting now :)

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl + , to open User Settings
Scroll down to Cucumber Auto Complete
On the right side you need to modify these settings (you can find 2 examples of how to do this on the extension page). In my case, I added the following:

[image]

Open a .feature file and right click any step, you should have Go To Definition and Peek Definition working.

Comment: Hey thanks for helping me. Sorry I didn't post my settings.json in my question, My bad. Actually I have configured it in many ways, yet wasn't successful. I tried just the path, absolute path too, relative path too..But non of it worked. You can see my project structure in the screenshots and my settings.json file in the screenshots. Would you help me were I have gone wrong? the curly lines are still displayed and I'm unable to go to my step definition from Feature file. Thanks in advance Man..!! :)

Comment: Change the settings.json file, line 2 to this:   "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "featureFiles/*.feature"

Answer (score 0):

Try putting settings.json into %AppData%\Code\User\settings.json

This solved this issue for me but not sure how your roaming profile is configured so might need to investigate which directory it is expected to be in.